# time rangeseekbar in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recents

I am using org.florescu.android.rangeseekbar.RangeSeekBar for time selection as I need to filter the result between selected time. I was fortunate enough to get this thing working for price but now I am stuck on time selection as it accepts only int, double and float values. but time is in string format 
I tried https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/771 which worked. and gave me below result:-

[image]

But it fails for minute selection(As it only provides hours) and also I need to do something like:-
[image]

Please help me out

Comment: HI Anil, did you solve this question ? please let me now. I am stucked for last 2 days bro :(

Comment: @nihal_softy :  yes nihal I have found an alternative... Please check the answer and lemme know if you find any problem..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

int SMALLEST_HOUR_FRACTION = 60;

seekbar.setOnRangeSeekBarChangeListener(new RangeSeekBar.OnRangeSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRangeSeekBarValuesChanged(RangeSeekBar bar, Object minValue, Object maxValue) {
                int minHour = seekbar.getSelectedMinValue().intValue() / SMALLEST_HOUR_FRACTION;
                int minMinute = (seekbar.getSelectedMinValue().intValue() % SMALLEST_HOUR_FRACTION);
                int maxHour = seekbar.getSelectedMaxValue().intValue() / SMALLEST_HOUR_FRACTION;
                int maxMinute = (seekbar.getSelectedMaxValue().intValue() % SMALLEST_HOUR_FRACTION);

```
            String dep_min_time = (String.valueOf(minHour)+ ":" + String.valueOf(minMinute));
            String dep_max_time = (String.valueOf(maxHour)+ ":" + String.valueOf(maxMinute));

            dep_min_time1_txt.setText(DateUtil.TimeFormat(dep_min_time));
            dep_max_time1_txt.setText(DateUtil.TimeFormat(dep_max_time));



        }
    });
```